# Example of an Outcome of Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems

Tags: logic, incompleteness

If you look up Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems, you will often read that a consequence of them is that some recognizable truths about arithmetic are unprovable given the set of axioms of arithmetic (the Peano Axioms?) Could anyone give me an example of such “recognizable truths?”

Answer (score 0):

There are actually *two* incompleteness theorems. The first states there are undecidable statements in a consistent system that proves the Peano axioms. The second states the system includes, but cannot prove, the statement that it's consistent.

For more directly arithmetical statements that are undecidable in the Peano axioms, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem).

Comment: I think "undecidable" is a wrong description.  The statements are true but not provable, which is stronger and more interesting (IMO) than undecidable.  The links are accurate though.

Comment: @DanielV You're only calling them "true but not provable" because they're provable in one context but not another. In other words, they're undecidable in the latter: they can't be proven true there because they're not provable there, but nor can they be proven false there because they're true.